# WebSphere 9.0.0.7 is stuck in the starting phase

Tags: websphere

Last line of the StartServer.log says that

"[10/4/19 23:54:38:608 EDT] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status."

The above has been waiting for straight 15 hours.

Only the following logs got populated:

1. verbosegc.001.log
2. startServer.log
3. native_stderr.log
4. native_stdout.log

SystemOut.log is not populated. So, not able to get the exact error.

Additional details:
JVM Heap sizes are as follows
initialHeapSize="4096" maximumHeapSize="8192"

Have already installed an web application (ear) in the same server. Now, I'm just trying to restart the IBM WebSphere service through Windows Services.

Similar situation has happened thrice before and I had no option other than to uninstall and reinstall WebSphere 9.0.0.7.

Please help in resolving this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just realizedy you are on windows.  This still sort of applies, but using different commands on windows to check various bits.  Most importantly, make sure the service socket/port isn't in use already (as it sounds like you deployed once before) and that it's not having issues binding to an in use port (#2 below).

Lastly, windows server has very nuanced service ID / Group role policies that are typically setup for specific service scenarious and could potentially impact a new installation if the service ID or service Group didn't get the proper role policies applied.

I'm leaving my original reply below for folks on unix (hey it still *could* be a permission issue in windows too).  I dislike having to think about the mess that is windows so I'm hopeful someone else will come along and give you the details on what WAS requires regarding role & policies settings and directory permission specifics that might have been overlooked during installation.

You might also want to reference this on windows: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014557253&ps=25

or the links here sounds like they may be very useful in figuring out where the issue lies:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27923155/Webpshere-taking-30-mins-to-open-for-e-business.html

---

Check system basics (yes yes, trivial, but more often than not...disregard if already checked):

1. full filesystem (`df -m`)

   - (doubtful, but you never know, esp. with out-of-the-box cloud builds using only one FS for everything)
   - `/`
   - WAS installation FS
   - `/opt` (if installed here)
   - `/tmp`
   - `/var/log` (or `/var` if not a separate FS)
   - any other FS mentioned by the installation documentation or referenced in the configuration
2. socket in use / process already running (daemon already listening on the same port/socket e.g. `netstat -na |grep ::`)
3. check service id owner,group,and/or other read/write/execute permissions (pay particular attention to `umask` of install, esp. if done as root, vs. service ID's ability to read/write locations)
   vis-a-vis:

   - install directory
   - log directory
   - configuration directory
   - content directory
   - pid directory handoff from root (`/var/run`)
   - any library dependencies / directories outside of WAS (e.g. oracle DB library via `/etc/alternatives` linking)
   - (also ensure SELINUX permissions are correct)
4. If none of these, most likely an internal misconfiguration preventing it from completing initializaion which would require a more in-depth review of the configuration.

Comment: Thanks Pavman for your response. I went through the steps provided.
WebSphere's debug port (7777) process was somehow running from the previous instances. However, I missed out to check those process before (I concentrated on 9080 and 9043 ports only).

Once I killed the process in 7777 port, server started without any hastle.
I really appreciate your assistance on this.